# How to change route name in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have symfony app. Made upgrade from 4.4 to 5.4. Here is my composer.json

```
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "7.4.*",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-imagick": "*",
        "ext-intl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.2",
        "dg/rss-php": "^1.4",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6.10|^2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.3|^2.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "friendsofsymfony/ckeditor-bundle": "2.4",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^3.6.0",
        "geoip2/geoip2": "^2.10",
        "google/recaptcha": "^1.2",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.5",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^6.2",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^4.22.4",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^4.9.1",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^4.6",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^5.5",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
        "symfony/asset": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/process": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/translation": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.2",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.4.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "php bin/console cache:clear": "script",
            "php bin/console assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "script"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

When I log in to /admin, I'm catching error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "admin_sonata_media_media_create" as such route does not exist.").

Output of route list:

```
php bin/console debug:router | grep media
  api_media_list                             POST       ANY      ANY    /api/v1/media/                                      
  api_media_filters                          GET        ANY      ANY    /api/v1/media/filters/                              
  api_media_item                             GET        ANY      ANY    /api/v1/media/{code}/                               
  admin_app_media_media_list                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/media-media/list                         
  admin_app_media_media_create               ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/app/media-media/create
.....
```

As I can see, I have this route named as `admin_app_media_media_create`. How to change it in template rendering?

I've searched for combinations 'admin_sonata*' in code with different combinations of this words. No app configs found.

Comment: Question is solved. I had edited config for CKEditor, where was hardcoded route names.

Comment: If the solution was trivial, it may be best to delete the question. Decide whether the solution would be useful for other readers.